# SageMaker Ground Truth with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker, labeling

I've seen examples of labeling data using SageMaker Ground Truth and then using that data to train off-the-shelf SageMaker models. However, am I able to use this same annotation format with TensorFlow Script Mode?

More specifically, I have a tensorflow.keras model I'm training using TF Script Mode, and I'd like to take data labeled with Ground Truth and convert my script from File mode to Pipe mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am from Amazon SageMaker Ground Truth team and happy to assist you in your experiment. Just to be clear our understanding, are you running TF model in SageMaker using TF estimator in your own container (https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/README.rst)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Not using my own container currently, using TensorFlow estimator and Script Mode with framework version 1.12 and py3.

Comment: yes, you can use Ground Truth augmented manifest to train a TF model with SageMaker using Pipe Mode and recordio wrapper type. Please follow this doc: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-extensions